# Schedule a mail on the 1st day of the following month

Tags: rules

I currently have a rule set up using scheduler which - when a user logs in, a rule component is scheduled to send a mail '+1 week' from this time.  This works fine.

However, I need to alter this so when the user logs in - the component mail is scheduled for the 1st of the following month.

Essentially, for example: if a user logs in today 16-06-14 - the component is scheduled to be executed on the 01-07-14.

Any ideas? Not sure how to set the offset. Would this be better via cron instead?

Comment: I think yes, I had similar requirement.I used hook_cron  to send mail notifications to user(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **"first day of +1 month"** as your scheduled date.

Comment: Legend, cheers!