# How to schedule a Rules component at the end of the month?

Tags: 7, rules, flags

The users on my website can flag articles with Flag. I want them to be able to do this exactly once every month, but they do not have permission to unflag content. Therefore, my plan is to create a Rule that triggers when an article is flagged and that schedules a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) component that takes care of the unflagging.

How can I schedule this component at the end of the month, i.e. which value should I add in the field *Scheduled evaluation date* of the action *Schedule component evaluation*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introducing `last day of 23:59` works for me (`last day of` is the last day of the current month, and `23:59` just before the day ends). You can see the full reference of DateTime relative formats here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

In general, you can pass anything recognised by `strtotime()` as the scheduling date.

Comment: Cool! Is the component then by default scheduled at midnight of the last day?

Comment: By default it is scheduled at the current time of the day. If you need it at a given time, it needs to be specified explicitly. I have just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems a variation of "[Schedule a mail on the 1st day of the following month](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118412/schedule-a-mail-on-the-1st-day-of-the-following-month)", which has an accepted answer like so:

> Try **"first day of +1 month"** as your scheduled date.

With that, you may get it to work by using something like **"last day of +0 month"** as your scheduled date, or maybe simply  **"last day of month"**.

Another approach (plan b ?) might be to try to use the "***Day of the month***" Rules Condition that comes with the [Rules Ones per Day](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_onceperday) module. Though in that case you have to specify an integer for the `monthday` (between 1 and 31). So to make that work for each month (with 31, 30, 29 or 28 days) you might end up with pretty complicated Rules logic (possibly combined with the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module to consolidate it all in a single rule). If however it would be acceptable for your case, I'd rather use "1st day of the month" (= 1 day later), which would avoid such complicated rule.